# how to make discord.py bot to send a specific message if the command is on cooldown

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord.py bot have a command which a user can use only once an hour. I want the bot to send a message "The command is on cooldown" when someone uses the command more than once an hour. This is the code for the command:

```
bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def on_message(message):
    await message.channel.send("hello")

bot.run("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: You probably want to use `discord.ext.commands` as mentioned in the answer. If you really need a "cooldown" on the event, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72119056/11107754)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cooldown on an on\_message event, discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72118914/cooldown-on-an-on-message-event-discord-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to create commands for your bot - you better use `ext.commands` extension part of the `discord.py` library. It prevents spaghetti code, gives better perfomance, it's easier to understand and there is command cooldown functionality, needed for your question and many more benefits. Thus I should send you to read [docs for `ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) or [part of the library FAQ about it](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#commands-extension)
2. Anyway, you already figured out that cooldowns are made with `@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)` but the way it works - it triggers error `commands.CommandOnCooldown` when user is on cooldown and thus we need to write error handler to catch that and send specific message as an answer. Again, [link to read](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling), [gist](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/7822af90858ef65012ea500bcecf1612). But in my example below I use local error handler for the `!test` command and if `error` is indeed of type `commands.CommandOnCooldown` - the bot will send "The command is on cooldown." as a response.

So MRE would look something like this.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True  # dont forget to optin them on dev portal

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix='!',
    intents=intents
)


@commands.cooldown(1, 60*60, commands.BucketType.user)
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send("hello")


@test.error
async def test_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f"The command is on cooldown.")


bot.run("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

Comment: Not a good idea to blindly use all intents. You'll also get into trouble if your bot ever goes big. Only add the intents you need (message content, etc)

Comment: @EricJin agree, edited code to reflect the suggestion. Quite lazy from me, my bad, sorry, but usually new people struggle with `intents`

Comment: No problem. Also, I always thought that the `bot.command` goes above any checks/cooldowns/stuff. But I guess if it works, it works and I'm just being weird.

Comment: what are the intents?

Comment: @Maxisy  discord requires users declare what sort of information (i.e. events) they will require for their bot to operate. In library this is done in the form of [intents - read here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)